# Is there a word for when the name of something describes or defines how it is made?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, meaning-in-context, terminology

I am wondering if there is a word for this as described in the title.

My example: I am writing about a SWANA ingredient/food product by the name of "Freekeh", which is based on the Arabic word "farik" which means "rub". Freekeh is produced by burning young green durum wheat, and then rubbing vigorously on coiled basket mats to remove the chaff and reveal the edible wheat berry. So, I am looking for a word that describes the relationship of the name of the end result to the activity by which it is produced, but can't quite find the right word to describe this etymological/embodied relationship to the nomenclature.  The closest thesaurus suggestions were appellative or epithet which are both...wrong.

I am looking for a word that would allow me to speak to this reflexive nature of including the instructions on how to make this in the name of it.

Is there a word that describes the naming of something by the action that begets it? I am not asking for literal examples of a rubbing, nor of chopping or mopping, or other verbs. I am asking for the word that DESCRIBES the reflexive quality of naming something based on how it is produced.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150912/discussion-on-question-by-freekehfreak-is-there-a-word-for-when-the-name-of-some); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score -1):

You might find **metonymy** to be close enough. Metonymy happens when referring to a concept by using something closely associated with that concept, as explained e.g. [in Merriam's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metonymy) . For example, when one inherits "the throne", really one is inheriting the position rather than just the literal seat. I said this is "close enough" because metonymies are usually noun-to-noun rather than verb-to-noun; however, I don't think metonymies refer only to noun-to-noun cases. So, in this case, you would be referring to the product by using the process that created it.

Comment: The OP is not seeking a term for 'referring to a concept by using **something** closely associated with that concept'; the question is about referring to objects by the terms derived **specifically** from the terms for the process by which these objects are created.